# Enums deserializing in Dart

Tags: dart

I implement an Observable pattern for some of my active components. They all mix in an Observable class that looks like this:

```dart
abstract interface class Events implements Enum {}

mixin Observable<T extends Events> {
  final Map<T, List<Function>> subscriptions = {};

  @protected
  void notifySubscribers(T event, [Map<Symbol, dynamic> args = const {}]) async {...}

  void subscribe(T event, Function callback) {...}

  void unsubscribe(T event, Function callback) {...}
}
```

Now, I need to pass events over the network and hence need to serialize them. For that I have another class that is descendent of `Observable` and aimed to events from the "other side".

```dart
abstract class DualObservable<T extends Events> with Observable<T> {
  @protected
  void notifyDualSubscribers(T event, [JSON? args]) {
    ...
    sendEvent(
        operation: 'notifySubscribers', args: {'event': event.name, 'args': args});
  }

  @protected
  void commHandler(JSON data) {
    if (data['operation'] == 'notifySubscribers') {
      notifySubscribers(
          T.values.byName(data['event']), {for (var i in data['args'].entries) Symbol(i.key): i.value}); // <----- This doesn't work
    }
  }
}
```

Deserializing is however seems to be impossible. I expected the generic `T` class to be able to use `values` property of `Enum` given that it is its descendant. However it's not the case.

Is there other way to deserialize an `Enum` descendant and not use strings as event names?

I can't use `mirrors` because that module will be used in Flutter applications as well.